# whats wrong with this swift code? indexing a tuple

Tags: swift, indexing, tuples

```
var xypos: (Int, Int) = (x: 0, y: 0)

var nextxy: (Int, Int) = (one: 1, two: 2)

if x == 7 {
    nextxy.one = 0
} else if y == 63 {
    nextxy.two = 0
}
```

I get an error saying tuple nextxy has no member one or two. Ive used the same syntax and copied out of a book.

Answer (score 2):

This code is right:

```
var xypos: (Int, Int) = (x: 7, y: 0)
var nextxy: (Int, Int) = (one: 1, two: 2)

if xypos.0 == 7 {
nextxy.0 = 0
} else if xypos.1 == 63 {
nextxy.1 = 0
}
print(xypos,nextxy)//xypos:7,0 nextxy:0,2
```

if you want access tuple by instance

```
var xypos: (x: Int,y: Int) = (2,2)
var nexttxy:(one: Int,two: Int) = (1,2)
if xypos.x == 7 {
    nexttxy.one = 1
  }else{
    nexttxy.two = 0
 }
print(xypos,nexttxy)//xypos:(2,2) nexttxy:(1,0)
```

[for more information about tuple](https://appventure.me/2015/07/19/tuples-swift-advanced-usage-best-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if x == 7 {
    nextxy.0 = 0
} else if y == 63
    nextxy.1 = 0
}
```

This is what you need to do to fetch values at index.

Answer (score 1):

And this should be ok as well:

```
var xypos: (x: Int, y: Int) = (x: 0, y: 0)

var nextxy: (one: Int, two: Int) = (one: 1, two: 2)

if xypos.x == 7 {
    nextxy.one = 0
} else if xypos.y == 63 {
    nextxy.two = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forcing the type of `nextxy` to be `(Int, Int)`, but you're expecting it to be type `(one: Int, two: Int)`. Tuple labels are a weak part of the type in Swift, and are easily lost (one reason that structs are usually a better tool than tuples). Swift is willing to add or throw away tuple labels as it needs to (in many cases they basically act like comments).

If you let type inference do its job (which you should anyway), then you'll get the behavior you're looking for, though:

```
var nextxy = (one: 1, two: 2)
```

Now the type of `nextxy` is `(one: Int, two: Int)`, which is what you're expecting.

Comment: Man I thought tuple labels, typedefs, label based indexing, etc. were really cool features of Swift, but it turns out people just abuse them as struct replacements. I can see why other languages wouldn't include such features

Comment: The deeper issue IMO is that Swift lacks an anonymous struct, which is a quite common feature.

Comment: What would the difference be between an anon struct and a tuple?

Comment: Structs are unordered and are strongly typed on their property labels. Go calls then anonymous structs which is the name that fits Swift best IMO, but other languages like SML, F#, and Haskell call them records.